# Pip/pipenv not finding package inside Docker container?

Tags: docker, python-3.7, pipenv

I'm trying to use [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) on my Python application who's development and deployment primarily happens in a Docker container, namely, [python:3.7-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/e057559fad64ed81b3da9fad6612a2de8b0ae544/3.7/alpine3.10/Dockerfile). When I run `pip install py-spy` locally in a virtualenv, it succeeds. Additionally, [pypi has a listing for it](https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/).

Strangely, when I include it in my Pipfile, `pipenv install` is unable to find it in the Docker container and fails when trying to build. *But it finds and installs the other Pipenv contents correctly.*

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.8
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN set -ex \
    && apk add libpq shadow \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
            gcc \
            git \
            bash \
            tmux \
            make \
            libcurl \
            curl-dev \
            libc-dev \
            musl-dev \
            linux-headers \
            pcre-dev \
            postgresql-dev \
            postgresql-libs \
            libffi-dev \
            ncurses-dev \
            python3-dev

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --dev

# This is where we fail
```

Without `py-spy`, the whole thing builds. With `py-spy = "*"`, running `pipenv lock && docker-compose build`, we get

```
An error occurred while installing py-spy==0.2.0.dev1 --hash=sha256:27f318826cb99a3cc4a089d8991e08ba8c86743ed9191799f39bc02cf1964a05 --hash=sha256:9e3d3f199c360dee58dbc9ce82e4dd9cb5ae3356466b25a8276bb972fdced2d9 --hash=sha256:c7c07b1557f372701ca3096582d487a19dd5ee7d0143c2c8dd3bdb0ec37c9450! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting py-spy==0.2.0.dev1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-jxl1heir-requirements/pipenv-8_kalqyx-requirement.txt (line 1))']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py-spy==0.2.0.dev1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-jxl1heir-requirements/pipenv-8_kalqyx-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)', 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for py-spy==0.2.0.dev1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-jxl1heir-requirements/pipenv-8_kalqyx-requirement.txt (line 1))']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

Does this ring any bells? `py-spy` has Rust dependencies, is there a way to check if its "invisible" to some architectures?

Comment: If possible can you provide complete `dockerfile`

Comment: good call, added! Also added breadcrumb, on `py-spy` having Rust dependencies (maybe the author listed, somehow, "make me invisible to architectures that aren't in [list]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [this](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy#running-py-spy-in-alpine-linux):

> Alpine python opts out of the manylinux wheels: [pypa/pip#3969 (comment)](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3969#issuecomment-247381915). Before installing py-spy on Alpine docker containers do:
>
> `echo 'manylinux1_compatible = True' > /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_manylinux.py`